# React-Native-Element icon shows up as cross in search bar

Tags: react-native, icons, font-awesome, searchbar

How do I change the icon of search bar in react-native-element.

```
<Icon type='font-awesome' name="share-alt" size={33} color="red" />
```

The above code does render the icon properly.

But the same icon shows up as a cross in the following code

```
<SearchBar
    lightTheme
    icon = {"share-alt", "red"}
    inputStyle={{margin: 0, padding:3, flex:1}}
    containerStyle={{flex:1, height:undefined}}
    onChangeText={() => {}}
    placeholder='ABC' />
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include screen shots?

Comment: Added a screen shot

Answer (score 1):

You can only change native icon only. It's list in here https://material.io/icons/.

icon prop does not accept type . It is specify here [react-native-elements/API/searchbar/](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/searchbar/)

```
 object {name (string), color (string), style (object)}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your screen shots, **react-native-vector-icons** is not installed properly. 
1. Install [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android) correctly. 
2. And then you can see search icon. At that time, you can change the icon of search bar. You can use [Material icon names](https://design.google.com/icons/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have linked the vector icons after installing them

```
npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

Then make sure you stop your packager and recompile the app again. now the icons should show up. The icons are not usually loaded up after installing and linking, you must recompile the app again.